# How are these angled brackets breaking my regular expression?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to capture the contents of a bespoke html-style tag within some data.

Then I'd like to  replace the contents AND surrounding tag with a placeholder.

I'm using objMatch.Value and objMatch.SubMatches(0)  to access the "contents + tag" and "contents only" respectively. However, the angled brackets of the tag appear to be causing both of these to return JUST the contents.

**This Breaks:**

```
"<MyTag\b[^>]*>(.*?)</MyTag>"
```

Both objMatch.Value and objMatch.SubMatches(0) return the contents only.

**This Works:**

...but if I change all angled brackets to dollar signs, like this:

```
"$MyTag\b[^$]*$(.*?)$/MyTag$"
```

objMatch.Value returns "contents + tag", and objMatch.SubMatches(0) returns "contents only".  As expected and desired.

Can anybody explain why this is, and / or how I can change my regex pattern to solve it?

**Full Code**

```
    Dim oRegEx
    Set oRegEx = New RegExp
    oRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    oRegEx.Global = True
    oRegEx.Pattern = "<MyTag\b[^>]*>(.*?)</MyTag>"   
    dim matches()
    dim replacements()
    dim i: i = 0
    dim objMatch

    For Each objMatch in oRegEx.Execute(stringToTest)
       redim preserve matches(i)
       redim preserve replacements(i)
       replacements(i) = objMatch.Value
       matches(i) = objMatch.SubMatches(0)
       i = (i + 1)
    Next
```

Comment: I have tested here and it seems to work as expected.... what am I doing wrong?!? [gskinner.com/RegExr/?35hgj](http://regexr.com?35hgj)

Comment: Is there any possibility that however you are viewing the results is rendering `<MyTag>` and such as tags, and they are just not visible to you there?

Comment: Code works just fine for me.

Comment: @femtoRgon - There is every chance. I feel such a **** (insert choice of expletive). Thank you so much.